Problema descargando archivo excel con PhpSpreadsheet
necesito actualizar la descarga de archivos en excel desdes PHP a traves del navegador. Antes usaba PHPExcel sin problema pero esta libreria ya no funciona desde que actualice mi version de php a la 8.2.8. Estoy probando con PhpSpreadsheet, pero no consigo que funcione, el script se ejcuta sin ningun tipo de error aparente, pero simplemente no se descarga nada.
Trabajo con IIS, windows Server 2022 y SQL Server
Se agradece cualquier sugerencia
Adjunto script:


<?php     

require 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/shimin_hh/vendor/autoload.php'; // Include Composer's autoloader
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;


$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$activeWorksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$activeWorksheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myfile.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

ob_end_clean();
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
exit;

?>




Probé tu aplicación generando el proyecto con Composer y PHP 8.3, bajando la librería composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet y usando el autoload que genera automáticamente en vendor/autoload.php. Y todo funciona perfectamente. Verifica que tu autoload esté correcto. Otra cosa es que phpspreadsheet requiere varias extensiones habilitadas en php.ini.
